# Turn off extension in Control Panel

Tags: add-on, extension, hook, session-end-hook

I would like to make sure an extension isn't run, via [sessions_end hook](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/global/session/index.html#sessions-end), in the control panel.

I'm currently doing this like so:

```
if ($this->EE->input->get_post('D') == "cp")
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

My question: is there a better or prefered method of having an extension only run a hook on the frontend and not in the CP?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That should work fine, but you can also check the `REQ` constant ([docs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/constants.html#request-constants)) which has the following possible values:

- `CP` - Control panel requests
- `PAGE` - Frontend template requests
- `ACTION` - Module actions, e.g. mysite.com/?ACT=123

For example:

```
if (REQ == 'CP')
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: On StackExchange the best answers include code examples even if it's very obvious :)

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing :)

Comment: Alright nitpickers, edit duly approved. :P

Comment: This is the exact same way that I do it Nate.

Comment: Cool. I always just tested for `$this->EE->cp`, but this way seems more solid.