# Different $base_url for CP versus public site?

Tags: assets

I have a unique situation where I'm reverse-proxying an EE site into another domain via Akamai. The origin hostname of the EE site is smallbusiness.pb.com and Akamai rewrites sends traffic coming in via www.pb.com/smb to that URL.

In order to make Structure navigation listings have the correct endpoint URL, I had to modify my Focus Lab LLC configuration by adding the following to my config.prod.php file:

```
$base_url = $protocol . 'www.pb.com' . '/smb';
```

Everything has been fine since I have been manually deploying from staging to production by synching the database and rsyncing files.

Now that I'm rolling out BetterWorkflow, however, I'm running into 403 Forbidden on Assets image thumbnail requests. Those requests are to the www.pb.com/smb URL instead of smallbusiness.pb.com.

Here's a sample of the error:

```
Request URL:http://www.pb.com/smb/?ACT=59&file_id=2&size=67x67&hash=1352925992
Request Method:GET
Status Code:403 Forbidden
```

#### Request Headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:[redacted]
Host:www.pb.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://smallbusiness.pb.com/smb/admin.php?S=0&D=cp&C=content_publish&M=entry_form&channel_id=3&entry_id=10&parent_id=0
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.56 Safari/537.17
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
ACT:59
file_id:2
size:67x67
hash:1352925992
```

#### Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Wed, 23 Jan 2013 21:34:55 GMT
Expires:Wed, 23 Jan 2013 21:34:58 GMT
Server:Apache
Set-Cookie:exp_last_activity=1358976898; expires=Thu, 23-Jan-2014 21:34:58 GMT; path=/
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

What I'm looking for is a way in my configuration file to have one base_url when browsing the control panel via smallbusiness.pb.com and another base_url when the public site is browsed via www.pb.com.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Without actually testing this maybe you could use a [Request Contant](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/constants.html#request-constants) along with a conditional like so in your FocusLab config file:

```
if (REQ == 'CP')
{
    $base_url = $protocol . 'smallbusiness.pb.com';
}
else
{
    $base_url = $protocol . 'www.pb.com' . '/smb';
}
```

You could edit this how you see fit of course though, it's a basic example/start.

Again, please test and let us know :)

Comment: This looks great, Nate. I'll check it out with some mods and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Nate, you're a genius and a lifesaver, AGAIN! Thank you !

Comment: Well, I can't take full credit for this one, maybe only partial credit. Take a look at this question [here](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13/turn-off-extension-in-control-panel) to see what I mean and note the answer :)

Comment: Spoke too soon. The normal entry page now shows Assets thumbnails. The last remaining issue is with the Assets modal that slides down from the top when adding new images. I'm still getting www.pb.com URLs there.

Any idea how to determine the request type for those?

Comment: Could this have to do with your [File Upload Preferences](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/content/files/file_upload_preferences.html#overriding-upload-paths-and-urls-using-configuration-variables)?

Comment: Actually, I think I just resolved it with this conditional:

    if (REQ == 'CP' || REQ == 'ACT' || AJAX_REQUEST)

Answer (score 0):

The information Nate posted was quite helpful. Based on that and some reading on the link he posted, I was able to come up with the following, which I added to config.master.php:

```
    switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
        case 'smb-staging.pb.com' :
            $base_url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/smb';
        break;

        case 'smbdev.pb.com' :
            $base_url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/smb';
        break;

        default :
            if (REQ == 'CP' || REQ == 'ACT' || AJAX_REQUEST)
            {
                $base_url = $protocol . 'smallbusiness.pb.com' . '/smb';
            } else {
                $base_url = $protocol . 'www.pb.com' . '/smb';
            }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Darn, I should have tested this further. Now Structure page URLs are rendering as smallbusiness.pb.com. Somehow that exp:structure:nav tag is interpreted as CP or ACT and all of my base_urls are rendering incorrectly.